# How to check other radio inputs before toggling state

Tags: jquery

The following code works, but there are multiple row siblings before the div.alert-warning is found and this causes problem when scores are changed.  When a row is '2' it shows the warning, and and if I change that row it disappears, but when it disappears, if there is a different row with a score of 2 I need it to keep showing the warning.  How can I alter the following to check if any other radios have a score of 2 or less before hiding an element when one row if changed to > 2?  Any help would be fantastic.

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() <= 2) {
          $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('div.alert-warning').show();
     } else {
          if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() > 2) {
                 $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('div.alert-warning').hide();
          }
     }
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
          @foreach ($evaluationForm as $form)
          <tbody class="mb-3">
            <tr class="bg-primary">
              <td class="header">{{ $form->title }}</td>
              <td class="header">SCORE</td>
            </tr>
            @if ($form->question_1)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $form->question_1 }}</td>
              <input type="hidden" name="{{ $form->category }}_question_1" value="{{ $form->question_1 }}">
              <td class="text-nowrap text-right">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_1" value="4">
                  <label>4</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_1" value="3">
                  <label>3</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_1" value="2">
                  <label>2</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_1" value="1">
                  <label>1</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_1" value="0">
                  <label>0</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_1" value="3.1">
                  <label>NA</label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            @if ($form->question_2)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $form->question_2 }}</td>
              <input type="hidden" name="{{ $form->category }}_question_2" value="{{ $form->question_2 }}">
              <td class="text-nowrap text-right">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_2" value="4">
                  <label>4</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_2" value="3">
                  <label>3</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_2" value="2">
                  <label>2</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_2" value="1">
                  <label>1</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_2" value="0">
                  <label>0</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input required type="radio" name="{{ $form->category }}_2" value="3.1">
                  <label>NA</label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            <tr>
              <td colspan=2>
                  <div class="alert alert-warning show" role="alert">
                      <strong>A comment is required!</strong> When a score of 2 or less is given.
                    </div>
                <strong>Comments</strong><br>
                <textarea id="comment" class="form-control comment" name="{{ $form->category }}_comment" rows="5"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          @endforeach
        </table>
```

There are actually up to 5 questions that may appear, I shortened the code to 2 question as you'll get that idea.

Comment: Are you saying that when it falls into the else logic, it hides radios in other rows that have a radio with a value less than two selected?

Comment: Side note; do not do `$(this).is(':checked')`.  If you already have a reference to an Element, use the `this.checked` property directly.

Comment: @Taplar correct. The rows are all part of one common category. Each row is a different question related to the category.  The warning comes at the end of rows above a comment box that warns them that a comment is required if the score is 2 or less.

Comment: Is the comment that you **do** want to hide in the same row as the radio you selected?  Or is there just one comment for all the rows?

Comment: @Taplar No, it's one bootstrap alert at the end of the rows all related to the category.

Comment: Gotcha, one sec.

Comment: Include the HTML please. I can't visualize `$(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('div.alert-warning').hide();` and it's a waste of time if your HTML doesn't match and we are guessing (a possibility since you have a problem)

Comment: HTML added.  Thanks

Comment: Wait, so you have just one table, with multiple tbody's?

Comment: Shoot, sorry yes.  My apologies.

Comment: Ok, my answer below should be scoped to use the closest tbody for the logic, rather than the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input:radio').on('change', function(){
  // use only the radio buttons belonging to the table the radio changed belongs to
  var $tbodyRadios = $(this).closest('tbody').find('input:radio');
  // lookup the warning element
  var $warning = $(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('div.alert-warning');
  
  // look to see if any of the check radio buttons have a value of 2 or less
  if ($tbodyRadios.filter(function(index, radio){ return radio.checked && radio.value <= 2; }).length) {
    // a radio with a value of 2 or less is checked, show the warning
    $warning.show();
  } else {
    // otherwise, hide the warning
    $warning.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Now nothing happens when they are selected. No warnings in the console.

Comment: @twoarmtom i had an error in the filter.  First argument to filter is the index, not the element.  Try it again.

Comment: That worked great, but there is one other problem.  I am looping each category with a new <table> element.  The code is also affecting the other tables.  I'm guessing you can limit to the current table?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would affect multiple tables as it is finding the div with in the sibling `tr` of the radio changed.  The `tr` in the other tables would not be siblings.  At this point I would really need to see an example of your html.  Or wait, you're saying that the radio buttons from other tables are affecting the table in which the radio changed, belongs?

Comment: @twoarmtom  alright, modified.  It should only evaluate the radio buttons in the table to decide if it should show the warning for the table.

Comment: I added  the HTML

Comment: the evaluate radio button in table edit does nothing. Hopefully the the HTML will help.

Comment: Please see my comment to your question.  if there is only a single table, and this logic needs to be scoped to the tbody, I'll just have to change the anser to use `var $tableRadios = $(this).closest('tbody').find('input:radio');` rather than the closest table

Comment: THANK YOU!  That works perfectly and your comments in the code allow me to understand exactly what you did.  Again, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem.  Glad we got you and understandable solution, :)